# how to specify a port in php code

Tags: php, ftp

We are getting this error:

> Warning: ftp_get(): Could not open data connection to port 51461: Connection timed out in /home/USER/public_html/SCRIPT/fetch_scripts/noose.php on line 39

Line 39:

```
ftp_get($CONNECTION_ID, '../ftp-in' . $SAVE_DIRECTORY . "/" . $SAVE_FILE_AS, $FTP_REMOTE_FILENAME, FTP_ASCII);
```

But initial ftp setup is as follows, is there a way to map the port to required 21 for this SITE?

```
<?
ini_set("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(-1);
//-------SYSTEM COMMANDS-------//
set_time_limit(0);
$start_time = time();

//-------CONFIGURE START-------//
$remote_server = 'ftp.SITE.com';
$remote_username = 'SITEFEED';
$remote_password = 'PASSWORD';
$remote_file = 'DATA.csv';
$local_save_path = '/DIRECTORY';
$local_save_filename = 'FILE.txt';
//-------CONFIGURE END-------//
//-------EXECUTION CODE-------//
fetch($remote_server,$remote_username,$remote_password ,$remote_file,$local_save_path, $local_save_filename);
//-------FUNCTIONS-------//
function fetch($FTP_SERVER,$FTP_USERNAME,$FTP_PASSWORD,$FTP_REMOTE_FILENAME,$SAVE_DIRECTORY,$SAVE_FILE_AS){
//MAKE CONNECTION...
$connected = 1;
$CONNECTION_ID = ftp_connect($FTP_SERVER);
if(!($CONNECTION_ID)){
    echo "<font color = 'red'>Could not connect to FTP_SERVER: " . $FTP_SERVER . ".</font><br>";
    $connected = 0;
}
$login_result = ftp_login($CONNECTION_ID,$FTP_USERNAME,$FTP_PASSWORD);
if((!$login_result)){
    echo "<font color = 'red'>Check FTP_USERNAME & FTP_PASSWORD for " . $FTP_SERVER . ".</font><br>";
    $connected = 0;
}
//IF CONNECTED...
if($connected == 1){
    if(!is_dir('../ftp-in' . $SAVE_DIRECTORY)) { mkdir('../ftp-in' . $SAVE_DIRECTORY); }
    ftp_get($CONNECTION_ID, '../ftp-in' . $SAVE_DIRECTORY . "/" . $SAVE_FILE_AS, $FTP_REMOTE_FILENAME, FTP_ASCII);
}
}
echo "<table><tr><Td><b>PAL FTP File Downloaded:</b></td><td>ftp-in/DATA/FILE.txt</td><td><i>Total Time: " . ( time() - $start_time) . " seconds.</i></td></tr>";
$start_time = time();
include("../db_import_scripts/pal_db_import.php");
?>
```

Comment: Port 21 is the default for the FTP control connection. The error is probably referring to the data connection, which uses an ephemeral port.

Comment: Here is exact code:  <tried to add but too long>

Comment: Don't try to put code in comments, edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

As Barmar pointed out, the port number that is generating an error is the local/temporary port being used for the FTP transport. When you connect to a remote FTP server on port 21, locally you are given a temporary port for use in the TCP connection which in your case is 51461. This is indicating that the FTP server may not be able to connect back to you.

If you are certain that the FTP server that you are making a connection to is valid/active/able to accept connections then try making a connection using the following code:

```
<?php

$local_file = 'local.zip';
$server_file = 'server.zip';

// setup connection 
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server); 

// login 
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) 
{
    echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
} 
else 
{
    echo "There was a problem\n";
}

ftp_close($conn_id); 

?>
```

If that does not work you may want to verify that a stateful firewall is not preventing the local port from accepting a connection back from the FTP server. Try disabling all firewalls and then try again.

Also, regarding your question about 'mapping to port 21'. If you make an FTP connection and do not specify a port then it is assumed that you will be using port 21 so an explicit mapping should not be required.

Sources:

1. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php

Comment: perfect, will try that.  this happened only since we moved nameservers to cloudflare for this domain - nice protection, nice interrupts.  Thanks!